# Is it possible to get Added items not committed in EFCore with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I need to query my Context in EF Core to get Added Items, but not Saved (EntityState.Added)

Example query:

```
var list = await _databaseContext.Set<PersonModel>().ToListAsync();
```

I see one topic about ChangeTracker, but I don't know how to implement here on this scenario.
Is it possible on EF Core?

Comment: `_databaseContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the changes with the `ChangeTracker` property on your `DbContext`:

```
var added = _databaseContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added);
```